# How many apples are there or How many apples there are?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions, word-order, subject-auxiliary-inversion

When I want to ask how many apples there is in the refrigerator, what is the correct sentence?

> 1) How many apples **are there**?
>
> 2) How many apples **there are**?

I asked this question because because that I know that questions that open them-self with question words they don't need question form in the following. For example: "Do you think that I am correct" (compare with: "do you think that **am I** correct" that is incorrect) but in this case that I raise here I have a doubt.

Comment: The first one is.

Comment: Yep number one is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declarative statements use "there are":

> There are some clouds in the sky.

Questions reverse the order:

> Are there some clouds in the sky?

In sentences such as "Do you know how many apples **there are**?" the phrase "how many apples there are" is not a question itself, it is a subordinate noun clause. The word order reversal comes in at "Do you know" (where a declarative statement would say "You do know").

Comment: "How many apples there are" is a [reported speech/indirect speech](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/reported-speech). You  need to be specific about it if you want to post your answer.

Comment: It is not indirect speech. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirect_speech) for a clearer explanation of what indirect speech entails.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my point. It is not describing some state of affairs. Is there Wikipedia link to show what "state of affairs" means?

Comment: In this case "how many apples there are" is a [subordinate noun clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause#Noun_clause). Subordinate clauses are used to add information to a sentence and are very common with sentences beginning "Do you know ...". A "state of affairs" is just another way of saying "situation"; I agree it's not a technical description of the construction but the final paragraph is tangential to the question anyway.

Comment: I think you got things mixed up. It's up to you to clear it up.

Comment: *You* thought it was something other than what it was (namely indirect speech), I was intentionally omitting details that I considered irrelevant to answering the question. The question has since been edited to ask specifically about subordinate clauses, which it didn't before. @Assiduous invalidated my answer with his edit so I am now editing my question to match it.